# How to add multiple signer in embedded sign through docusign api

Tags: nodes, docusignapi

I am new to docusign api. I am trying implement emebbed docment signing in my app using docu sign api. My requirement is need to  sign two persons on single document. I have seen some examples for that, I get url for single user signing, but I didn't get the right solution. Please help me. thanks in advance

Here is my sample code

```
var docusign = require('docusign-esign');
var async = require('async');
var integratorKey  = '*************',  
email            = '***********',
password         = '***********',      
recipientName    = '*********',   
recipientEmail   = '**********';
recipientName1    = '***********', 
recipientEmail1   = '*************'; 
var basePath = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";
const SignTest1File = "sample.pdf";
var envelopeId = '';
var apiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
apiClient.setBasePath(basePath);
var creds = JSON.stringify({
 Username: email,
 Password: password,
 IntegratorKey: integratorKey
});
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", creds);
docusign.Configuration.default.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);
async.waterfall([
 function login (next) {
  var authApi = new docusign.AuthenticationApi();
  var loginOps = new authApi.LoginOptions();
  loginOps.setApiPassword("true");
  loginOps.setIncludeAccountIdGuid("true");
  authApi.login(loginOps, function (err, loginInfo, response) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (loginInfo) {
      var loginAccounts = loginInfo.getLoginAccounts();
      console.log("LoginInformation: " + JSON.stringify(loginAccounts));
      next(null, loginAccounts);
    }
  });
},
function createAndSendEnvelopeWithEmbeddedRecipient (loginAccounts, next) {
  var fileBytes = null;
  try {
    var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');
    fileBytes = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('controllers/'+SignTest1File));
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log("Exception: " + ex);
  }
  var envDef = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
  envDef.setEmailSubject("Please sign this doc");
  var doc = new docusign.Document();
  var base64Doc = new Buffer(fileBytes).toString('base64');
  doc.setDocumentBase64(base64Doc);
  doc.setName("sample.pdf");
  doc.setDocumentId("1");
  var docs = [];
  docs.push(doc);
  envDef.setDocuments(docs);
  var signer = new docusign.Signer();
  signer.setName(recipientName);
  signer.setEmail(recipientEmail);
  signer.setRecipientId("1");
  signer.setClientUserId("1234");  
  var signHere = new docusign.SignHere();
  signHere.setDocumentId("1");
  signHere.setPageNumber("1");
  signHere.setRecipientId("1");
  signHere.setXPosition("100");
  signHere.setYPosition("100");
  var signHereTabs = [];
  signHereTabs.push(signHere);
  var tabs = new docusign.Tabs();
  tabs.setSignHereTabs(signHereTabs);
  signer.setTabs(tabs);
  envDef.setRecipients(new docusign.Recipients());    
  envDef.getRecipients().setSigners([]);
  envDef.getRecipients().getSigners().push(signer);
  envDef.setStatus("sent");
  var envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
  envelopesApi.createEnvelope(loginAccounts[0].accountId, envDef, null, function(error, envelopeSummary, response) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    }
    if (envelopeSummary) {
      console.log("EnvelopeSummary: " + JSON.stringify(envelopeSummary));
      envelopeId = envelopeSummary.envelopeId;
      next(null, envelopeId, loginAccounts);
    }
  });
},
function requestRecipientView (envelopeId, loginAccounts, next) {
  const returnUrl = "http://www.docusign.com/developer-center";
  var recipientView = new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();
  recipientView.setUserName(recipientName);
  recipientView.setEmail(recipientEmail);
  recipientView.setReturnUrl(returnUrl);
  recipientView.setAuthenticationMethod("email");
  recipientView.setClientUserId("1234"); 
  var envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
  envelopesApi.createRecipientView(loginAccounts[0].accountId, envelopeId, recipientView, function(error, viewUrl, response) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    }
    if (viewUrl) {
      console.log("RecipientViewUrl = " + JSON.stringify(viewUrl));
      next()
    }
  });
}
], function end (error) {
 if (error) {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
  process.exit(1);
 }
 process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Have you found solution to this? how to call CreateRecipientView for the second signer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have

```
envDef.getRecipients().getSigners().push(signer);
```

currently you are pushing only one signer in this collection. Create a new signer with `name, email, routingorder and clientUserId and its associated tabs`. Then push this new signer also to the signers collection, this way you can add multiple signers in an envelope. While creating an embedded signing url, you need to correctly refer the name, email and clientUserId for whom you want to create the URL, also please note you cannot generate the recipient url for a recipient if the workflow has not reached that signer.

Comment: Once the first user signs the document you are redirected to your own website. How and when would you do the second post request for CreateRecipientView() cause this methods takes three parameters envelopeId, accountId & options{returnUrl:'asd', clientUserId : '1234', AuthenticationMethod : 'email' and username,email}. envelopId will not be there anymore.

Comment: Have you found solution to this?

Comment: How to call createRecipientView for the second signer?